# How can I read the content of a file streamed with csv.writer?

Tags: python

I have a complex structure that involves an object (called mc from the class MyClass in the following simplified code) that is supposed to, on some occasions, add lines to a csv file (test1.csv and test2.csv in this example).

The program is actually a server that need to stay waiting in the end. Here I replaced the whole part with a pending input as I noticed the same problem occurs in this case.

Here is the simplified program:

```
import csv
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        csvfile = open("./test1.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
        stream = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        stream.writerow(["stream created"])

        csvfile2 = open("./test2.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
        self.stream2 = csv.writer(csvfile2, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        self.stream2.writerow(["stream2 created"])
    def do(self):
        self.stream2.writerow(["done"])

mc = MyClass()
mc.do()
_ = input("doing a pause")
```

So basically here I create an object "mc", creating at the same time two streams. stream1 gets closed when the initialization is over, with just one line being added, but stream2 is kept as an attribute for later use.

If I leave the input pending I can notice that both test1.csv and test2.csv were created, but test1.csv has the line I expect and test2.csv is empty (I would expect it to have the lines "stream2 created" and "done"). If I make the program finish then test2.csv becomes filled as I needed.

My problem is that I would like to check the contents of the files without ending my server and keep the possibility to write more of them. How can I do that?

Comment: the code is different for writing `stream` and `stream2`, is that on purpose ?

Comment: You mean `self.` before `stream2`? This is on purpose, because I want to keep stream2 as an attribute for later use.